# Gradle composite builds - can you have a dependency to a java sub-project from an included multi-project build?

Tags: java, gradle, build, dependencies

Let's say you have 2 gradle projects. The first is a multi project with 2 java sub-projects:

```
rootProject
    :my:subProject1
    :myother:subProject2
```

The second gradle project is a single project that includeBuild's the root project:

```
secondProject
    includeBuild '../rootProject'
```

I want to make a `compile` dependency of `:my:subProject1` into `secondProject.`

So basically I want to add the following to `secondProject`'s build.gradle file:

```
dependency {
    compile(project(':my:subProject1')) 
}
```

When I try to do that, it returns error: `Project with path ':my:subProject1' could not be found in root project 'secondProject'`

I seems like I can only resolve the dependency when I do the dependency as `group:artifact:version`. For example: `my.root.project:subProject1:1.0.0`. But why would it make me do that? Why not let me access the composite build's project hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only one settings.gradle should exist on the root, remove all setting.gradle files in any subfolders
2. Define the projects on the settings.gradle file of the root folder

   ```
   include ':sub1', ':sub2', ':sub3'
   ```
3. Add  `compile project(":sub1")` to your build.gradle under dependencies block:

   ```
   dependencies{
     compile project(":sub1")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is just how these composite builds work. They basically act as if you published the other project to maven local prior to including it. so this means you need to depend on the version number of the split project.